# aggregate value with time in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame;

```
Date <- as.Date(c('2006-08-23', '2006-08-30', '2006-09-06', '2006-09-13', '2006-09-20'))
order <- c("buy", "buy", "sell", "buy", "buy")
cost <- c(10, 15, 12, 13, 8)
df <- data.frame(Date, order, cost)
df
             Date order cost
     1 2006-08-23   buy   10
     2 2006-08-30   buy   15
     3 2006-09-06  sell   12
     4 2006-09-13   buy   13
     5 2006-09-20   buy    8
```

How can I sum the cost column by taking into account date and the order column and obtain the new balance column in a new data frame like this one?

```
             Date order cost balance
     1 2006-08-23   buy   10      10
     2 2006-08-30   buy   15      25
     3 2006-09-06  sell   12      13
     4 2006-09-13   buy   13      26
     5 2006-09-20   buy    8      34
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a sorted DF, "cost" is an unsmart label, since we will have to generate a sign to show what the actual cost was based on the buy/sell flag.

```
df$cost[df$order == 'sell'] <- -df$cost[df$order == 'sell']
```

balance is then `cumsum(df$cost)`.